# Webdriver-manager overflow virtual memory

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I'm using a Centos 7 server to run automatic e2e test by Jenkins. My stack consist in protractor test using webdriver-manager. Because i want to automate the process, i create a service to run webdriver from start. But after few builds failed, the webdriver increase the use of memory over my limit (2 GB physic + 2 GB virtual) and the server starts to fail. Any ideas or workaround?

I'm using webdriver-manager 10.1.0 with chromedriver 2.22, Selenium-standalone 2.53, and jenkins 2.10

Comment: My impĺementention use xvfb to run headless and the webdriver is used by few different task to run at the same time (in this moment, 2)

Comment: I have similar issue related with spec of the server which executing my e2e test. Even running on headless browser, it is still a heavy task, you need a decent spec to run it properly. For my case, 4 processors CPU (2.2GHz each), 4GB RAM, 128MB VRAM.

Comment: Are you using the local driverprovider feature? Or are you using `webdriver-manager start` and setting your Protractor config to `seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'`? Also, if you do `ps aux | grep selenium` how many instances of chromedriver, selenium-standalone are you seeing?

Comment: Please try the most up to date version. There was a bug that left chromedriver sessions opened. Thanks!